# SQLDEVELOPER: JDK Not Found with JDK-11 installed

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

when running $sqldeveloper in order to open the app it returns the next message:

```
Default JDK not found
Type the full pathname of a JDK installation (or Ctrl-C to quit), the path will be stored in /home/adri/.sqldeveloper/19.2.1/product.conf
```

I'm in ubuntu and there goes some info about my jdk installation:

$sudo update-alternatives --config java

```
There is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
```

$ls /usr/lib/jvm/

```
default-java           java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64  openjdk-11
java-11-openjdk-amd64  java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

$ls java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/

```
jconsole
```

When typing java-11-openjdk-amd64 in the sqldeveloper opened terminal (as it was asked) it turns into that message:

```
Error: java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java not found or not a valid JDK
```

So the file 'java' is needed but I don't have it :C

Thanks for attention.
Bests,

Comment: What version of sqldeveloper are you trying to use?

Comment: This page has installation instructions here. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-install-linux-1969676.html.  Did you do what the instructions say?

Comment: I think it's the latest: 19.2.1

Comment: I did, in fact it used to work but since I installed jdk8 everything messed-up

Comment: We don't support openJDK although it should work if 11 or higher..you're showing JREs which aren't enough

Comment: Go to $HOME/. sqldeveloper - open product.conf in the system.19.2.1.. folder, edit that file to point to a valid Java JDK home

Comment: it worked partially. For some reason it just doesn't work with openjdk (despite it used to) but  it does with JDK, i will post the solution as soon I check nothing has messed up. Thanks!

Comment: Well part of the problem is that you've not given us enough to work on to help you solve your problem, because it's clearly saying it needs a JDK (aka the `javac` command and family) but you've shown us the outputs locating your JRE ('java').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to add a comment as I am a new user here but I am wondering if there is something not quite right or missing in your environment.

I just created an Ubuntu 18.04 VM to match your o/s and used the Synaptic Package Manager to install openjdk-11-jdk (which installed a couple dependent packages as well). Here are the packages this process installed:

• openjdk-11-jdk
• openjdk-11-jdk-headless
• openjdk-11-jre
• openjdk-11-jre-headless

As [thatjeffsmith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1156452/thatjeffsmith) mentioned the JDK is required (so that SQL Developer can use the JDWP debugging capabilities).

I then unzipped the following SQL Developer package which I had previously downloaded:

• sqldeveloper-19.2.1.247.2212-no-jre.zip

After changing to the correct directory (~/Applications/sqldeveloper/19.2/sqldeveloper in my case) I started SQL Developer as follows:

./sqldeveloper.sh

I then imported my connections from a previous export and was able to connect successfully. I only did a few tests in the Worksheet and browsing objects owned by my user but I didn't encounter any issues using OpenJDK 11.

I had previously encountered issues with OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11 — you can read about that here:

[A Tale: SQL Developer 19.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 with OpenJDK 11 and OpenJFX 11](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4300880)

The essence of that thread is that I had "pre-installed" the OpenJFX **11** libraries and that caused a conflict with the OpenJFX **12** libraries that SQL Developer installed automatically.

If you are still trying to pursue this I recommend ensuring you have a the JDK installed and verify as I have done in the following:

```
markwill@ubuntu18-vm01:~$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
markwill@ubuntu18-vm01:~$ javac -version
javac 11.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still struggling with openJDK. It won't work.
For some reason it just doesn't work with openjdk (despite it used to) but it does with JDK.
Just go [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), download the *.rpm file and install it extracting with $sudo alien --scripts and $gdebi ./[Extracted_file].
Just provide sqldeveloper the  /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_181 path.

Thanks for the comments, I was going mad...

Comment: You can close this question by marking this as the answer (click on the grey tick at the left side of the answer and make it green).

Comment: You can accept your own answer in 2 days. But I will, thanks!

Comment: OpenJDK isn't supported but version 11 or higher should be ok